# git cherry picking showing previous revisions code in conflict

Tags: git, version-control, merge, cherry-pick

When using git cherry pick to merge revisions via commits we encounter the following issue of git showing other peoples code as part of the conflict resolution options.

Let's say we have the following history in the develop branch

```
A----B----1----2 develop
```

We want to merge the commit **revision 1** from develop to the release branch

```
A----T release
```

**Revision A for both develop and release branch start**

```
public interface Constants {
    String ConstantA = "CONSTANT_A";
}
```

**Revision B in develop**

```
public interface Constants {
    String ConstantA = "CONSTANT_A";
    String ConstantB = "CONSTANT_B";
}
```

**Revision 1 in develop**

```
public interface Constants {
    String ConstantA = "CONSTANT_A";
    String ConstantB = "CONSTANT_B";
    String Constant1 = "CONSTANT_1";
}
```

**Revision 2 in develop**

```
public interface Constants {
    String ConstantA = "CONSTANT_A";
    String ConstantB = "CONSTANT_B";
    String Constant1 = "CONSTANT_1";
    String Constant2 = "CONSTANT_2";
}
```

**Revision T in release**

```
public interface Constants {
    String ConstantA = "CONSTANT_A";
    String ConstantT = "CONSTANT_T";
}
```

When I switch to the release branch and cherry pick revision 1 I get conflicts as expected.

However the problem is how the conflict is shown, which is as follows

```
public interface Constants {
    String ConstantA = "CONSTANT_A";
<<<<<<< release
    String ConstantT = "CONSTANT_T";
=======
    String ConstantB = "CONSTANT_B";
    String Constant1 = "CONSTANT_1";
>>>>>>> 60dc0f9 Revision 1
}
```

The problem is the following line being present

```
String ConstantB = "CONSTANT_B";
```

When I go back to my development branch and diff Revision B and Revision 1 I get ONLY the following

```
String Constant1 = "CONSTANT_1";
```

Basically I am guessing this is because that Revision B commit is present before Revision A. In a real environment there can be lots more changes before the cherry pick commit that are not in the release branch (Imagine about 40 more constants added), how do I only get the actual diff of my cherry picked commit shown in the conflict. Note that I tried this with `rebase --onto` but got the same result.

**EDIT**

The following is the file after cherry picking with the conflict in the diff3 format. `git checkout --conflict=diff3 src/Constants.java`

```
public interface Constants {
    String ConstantA = "CONSTANT_A";
<<<<<<< ours
    String ConstantT = "CONSTANT_T";
||||||| base
    String ConstantB = "CONSTANT_B";
=======
    String ConstantB = "CONSTANT_B";
    String Constant1 = "CONSTANT_1";
>>>>>>> theirs
}
```

Comment: If you do `git checkout --conflict=diff3 filename`, then what is reported as base version?

Comment: can you explain the parameters diff3 and filename that I should use

Comment: `diff3` means that conflicted hunks should include not only ours and theirs version but also base version of hunk. And `filename` should be file where merge conflict arise.

Comment: Ran the command and changed the diff format to ours, base, theirs. Still a bit confused to as to how to check the base version though. Added the updated file with diff3 format in the question.

Comment: It looks like, when `git` want to `rebase` or `cherry-pick` commit `C` to current `HEAD`, then it does three-way merge with `ours=HEAD`, `theirs=C` and `base=C^` (parent of `C`). In your case it would be `ours=T`, `theirs=1` and `base=B`. From that point of view `theirs` side add just one line `CONSTANT_1`, but `ours` side remove `CONSTANT_B` line and add `CONSTANT_A` line. That removal of `CONSTANT_B` line in `ours` side make it to be part of conflicted hunk. So that, it included in `base` and `theirs` version of hunk.